# Can not to create new java with maven web project in NetBeans due Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I can not create new project in Apache NetBeans. I got error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection to Maven Central is [not using a supported TLS version](https://central.sonatype.org/articles/2018/May/04/discontinued-support-for-tlsv11-and-below/).